# Best Grouping Method

Tags: permutations, combinatorial-optimization

Let $\mathbf{x}_1,\mathbf{x}_2,\dots,\mathbf{x}_{2n}$ be real vectors with the following properties

$$\sum_{i=1}^{2n}\mathbf{x}_i=0$$ and $$\|\mathbf{x}_i\|_1=1$$

I want to find a **grouping** strategy to achieve the minimum of

$$\|\mathbf{x}_{i_1}+\mathbf{x}_{i_2}\|_1+\|\mathbf{x}_{i_3}+\mathbf{x}_{i_4}\|_1+\cdots+\|\mathbf{x}_{i_{2n-1}}+\mathbf{x}_{i_{2n}}\|_1$$

where $\|\cdot\|_1$ is the $\ell_1$ norm.

Comment: Erm... I'm not quite sure what your expression is when $n=3$

Comment: I would choose $x_{i_1}=-x_{i_2}$, $x_{i_3}=-x_{i_4}$ and so on. I think you need to clarify this question.

Comment: X-post: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2457852/339790

Comment: @BenMcKay I believe the vectors are *given* and one can only group them.

Comment: Yes, the vectors are given and one can only group them.